# How to set popupCollision configuration property of Kendo Menu using Asp.Net Mvc HtmlHelper?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-menu

The example for Kendo Menu documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/menu#configuration-popupCollision) sets the popupCollision property in Javascript. How can this property be set using Asp.Net MVC HtmlHelpers for Kendo Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Menu Builder ASP.NET MVC documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/menubuilder) there is not such property. Unfortunately this differeneces sometimes happens betveen JS and ASP versions like there are two other teams of developers.

MVC HTML Helper just generate JavaScript code, so you can try set it using JavaScript setOptions on document ready:

```
$("#menu").data('kendoMenu').setOptions({
    popupCollision: false
});
```

Or even better, use the javascript version in the first place if you need this property.